# Spotfire: Creating a details visualization with automatic filter change

Tags: expression, filtering, spotfire

I have a table (table 1) in Spotfire that shows counts for the month of January 2016 based on the filter "Drop Date". Is there a way to create a table that links to table 1 that will automatically show the data 1 year prior based on "Drop Date" without having to always change the filter for second table?

Example.
Table 1 shows counts with drop date 1/25/2016 (3rd drop date of 2016)

Table 2 connects to table 1 and will automatically show drop date 1/26/2015 (3rd drop date of 2015)

IF I change the filter on table 1 to drop date 2/1/2016 I would want table 2 to automatically change to drop date 2/2/2015. Additionally, if I choose drop date of 1/25/2016 and 2/1/2016 for table 1, I would want table 2 to show drop date 1/26/2015 and 2/2/2015.

Would I need something like "limit Data Using Expression" on table 2 using some code that represents 1 year prior of drop date on table 1?

Thank you!

Side question: What coding language is used for writing expressions in Spotfire?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way to compare data from previous years depending on how the data is structured. For example, you could add rows from one table and the other and use the over previous year function if you dates are unpivoted .

However, if you have no other options but have the tables separate and your table 1 has only 2015 data and table 2 only 2016 data, then it might work to add a data table relation by matching your date column by month (using a right/left Month method)

Side answer: it's a Spotfire proprietary language.